# Installing SuperSU with Twrp to root android

Tags: rooting, supersu

I am having trouble installing SuperSU from Twrp Recovery. The steps I used are as follows:

1. Boot into bootloader: `adb reboot bootloader`
2. Flash recovery to twrp image file: `fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.5.2_9-0-ali.img`
3. Open recovery mode, opens twrp
4. Twrp asks for decryption password, I don't know what to do so I
   press cancel
5. Twrp asks if I want to keep system read only
6. I swipe to allow modifications
7. I click install
8. I find /external_sd
9. I click UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.80.zip
10. I swipe to confirm flash
11. It says successful, but also says `unable to mount storage` `unable to mount /data/media/TWRP/.twrps`
12. I click wipe cache/dalvik
13. I swipe to wipe
14. I click reboot system
15. I input my password to start device
16. I look for the SuperSU app, I don't find it.

So something messed up and SuperSU didn't install. Any ideas?

Comment: How old is the device (which is it and what Android version runs on it)? Nowadays nobody installs SuperSU, everybody uses Magisk instead.

Comment: Its a Motorola G6, I can try Magisk later, but I think its a file access error.

Comment: 11 failed because you didn't pass 15 into 4